# How to I get the Haskell data value from the request body in Snap framework

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am new Snap and Haskell web development, I want to parse the request body to Haskell data value .

I have tried the example from this https://github.com/raimohanska/snap-skeleton/blob/master/src/Examples/Restful.hs . It seems to work , But wondering if there is any standard way to do this in Snap world .

Comment: the example is pretty neat - what do you mean with **standard way**?

Comment: In Java world there is Jackson to this . Is there any library that does this in Haskell world ?

Comment: does what? - parse JSON? The example is using it (look for AESON)